# How to add a Shadow on an UIImage

Tags: swift, uiimage, shadow

I have an Image with the following code:

`let image = UIImage(data:imageData)`

How can i add a *Shadow* to the Image?

I want it directly to the Image and NOT to the Imageview of the image. The hole Construct is for implementing the Image with Shadow in an PDF-Document.